# Equalize height of columns with different parent - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, height, equals

I'm using a jQuery snippet to equalize height of the columns in the dropdown megamenu:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var maxheight = 0;
    $('.menu .parent .dropdown .dropdown-inner .column').each(function(){
      if($(this).height() > maxheight) { maxheight = $(this).height(); }
    });

    $('.menu .parent .dropdown .dropdown-inner .column').height(maxheight);
});
```

And here it's HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul class="dropdown">

        <li class="parent item1">
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <div class="dropdown-inner">
            <div class="column1">
                <ol>
                    <li>sublink1</li>
                    <li>sublink2</li>
                    <li>sublink3</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
            <div class="column2">
                <ol>
                    <li>sublink1</li>
                    <li>sublink2</li>
                    <li>sublink3</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
            <div class="column3">
                <ol>
                    <li>sublink1</li>
                    <li>sublink2</li>
                    <li>sublink3</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>                                                                                                   

        <li class="parent item2">
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <div class="dropdown-inner">
            <div class="column1">
                <ol>
                    <li>sublink1</li>
                    <li>sublink2</li>
                    <li>sublink3</li>
                    <li>sublink4</li>
                    <li>sublink5</li>
                    <li>sublink6</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
            <div class="column2">
                <ol>
                    <li>sublink1</li>
                    <li>sublink2</li>
                    <li>sublink3</li>
                    <li>sublink4</li>
                    <li>sublink5</li>
                    <li>sublink6</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
            <div class="column3">
                <ol>
                    <li>sublink1</li>
                    <li>sublink2</li>
                    <li>sublink3</li>
                    <li>sublink4</li>
                    <li>sublink5</li>
                    <li>sublink6</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>                                                                                                                                       
    </ul>
</div>
```

I would like to adapt this jQuery snippet, so it would equalize columns for each parent item (li elements with classes item1 and item2), because columns (elements with classes column1 and column2) contain different number of links, which results in different heights of the wrapper element (div with class dropdown-inner). If you calculate height based on the highest element (with bigger number of links), you get too much white space in the element which has fewer links.

You can see this situation in these screenshots:

[image: smaller dropdown with too much white space]

[image: dropdown with bigger number of links]

Thanks for helping!

Comment: I have seen your website.Just try my answer.

Comment: The website you have seen is an old one, I'm working on a new site which is on local enviroment and the code is completely different.

Comment: Are you tried my answer ?

Comment: I didn't because as I said you looked at old code and your answer doesn't help. Thanks anyway.

Comment: ok try this `$(".dropdown-inner > div").css('min-height','0px')`

Answer (score 0):

I would loop through the dropdown and through the columns.
Remember the highest value and set that for the column of the dropdown.

```
$(dropdown).each(function () {
   Height = 0;
    $(this).find('column').each(function () {
       check if the height of this column is bigger than the var height
       if so set var height to new height
    });
    $(this).find('column').height(height);
});
```

Something like this.

Answer (score 0):

remove minimum height `min-height`

Try this,

```
$('.level-wrap').css('min-height','0px')
```

Update:

```
$(".dropdown-inner > div").css('min-height','0px')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this jQuery method to make any element equal height with any matched selector.

Create the method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery.fn.equalHeights = function(){
    var colSelector = this.selector;
    var newHeight;
    var colHeights = [];
    $(colSelector).each(function(){
      var singleCol = $(this).outerHeight();
      colHeights.push(singleCol);
      newHeight = Math.max.apply(Math,colHeights);
    });
    $(colSelector).css('height', newHeight+'px');
  }
});
```

Usage:

`$('.menu .parent .dropdown .dropdown-inner .column').equalHeights();`

Comment: I use this method all the time and it works. In your code they would all need to have the 'column' class or whatever matched class you want.